# Is it possible to add a property in only one replica of spring boot application deployed on Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes, deployment

watcher:
enabled: true

I have this above property that needs to be added only on single replica of spring boot application.

Comment: By definition *replica* means "an exact copy or model of something", therefore: no

Answer (score 1):

Basically I don't think so. The idea of replicas is for them to be the same. If you need just one different replica you could try deploying a single pod with a different configMap.